# SwipeRefreshLayout Freezes when using a runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need to refresh a `TextView` with a Swipe-to-Refresh Layout. The Problem is that it freezes when I use a `runOnUiThread` instead of a normal `Runnable` in a new `Thread` but if I use *that* the Application throws out the following error:
"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Code:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            MainClass();
                        }
                    });
                }
        );
```

**Any solution to this?**

Comment: what did you do in runOnUiThread

Comment: I call a class that updates' the TextView

Comment: @Hulk can you post your code please.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would expect that `onRefresh` is called on the main thread (because it is UI interaction from the user). Is it needed to call `runOnUiThread`? Can't you do it without any `Runnable`?

Comment: If I do it without any runnable the SwipeRefreshLayout also freezes

Comment: OK. Then I think that you don't need `runOnUiThread`, but something in `MainClass()` is happening that freezes. Can you post the content of that function?

Comment: I don't think so because if I use a normal Runnable it works (except that the App crashes because of the setText)

Comment: Where exactly does your app freeze? Does it freeze when the `Runnable` is executed or before it is posted to the ui thread?

Comment: The App doesn't freeze just the RefreshLayout

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'freeze' then?

Comment: The Animation of the SwipetoRefresh Layout works perfectly fine but when its pulled down, the progress animation stops until the Runnable is executed